# Is it possible to call another HTML doc, where an SVG is defined, and use it as an SVG in another HTML doc?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am thinking about the possibilities of working with SVG images and whether it is possible to store an SVG definition in a standalone HTML file e.g. below, blue-circle.html:

```
<html>
<body>

<title>Saved as blue-circle.html</title>

<h1>A bluecircle</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

and call it from another HTML file e.g.

```
<html>
<body>

<title>My Website</title>

<h1>Blah blah blah...</h1>

<svg width="100" height="100" url="blue-circle.html")/>
</svg>

<p>... ...</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The reasoning behind this is to:

- Avoid referencing SVG or raster files.
- Avoid saving SVGs in a raster format and using them via an img tag.
- Reduce the use of in-line SVG for every HTML doc (thus removing duplication and loads of text in single HTML files).
- Create a centrally stored vault of SVG's that can be referenced from any HTML file.

**Is it possible to call another HTML doc, where an SVG is defined, and use it as an SVG in another HTML doc?**

Comment: You can put the svg in a svg file and include as image.

Comment: Thanks @Johnny yes that is one method but I should have mentioned that this isn’t a preferred method...due to our setup...I’ll update the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put your SVGs in a single svg file and reference them via `<use>`

vault.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <svg id="symbol1" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="green"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="symbol2" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="blue"/>
  </svg>
  <svg id="symbol3" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
     <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red"/>
  </svg>
</svg>
```

some.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px">
      <use xlink:href="vault.svg#symbol1"/>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px">
      <use xlink:href="vault.svg#symbol2"/>
    </svg>
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="200px">
      <use xlink:href="vault.svg#symbol3"/>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

you can not however reference svg living in an external html file that way :-( it only work if the svg live in an extenal svg... there are many way to do get it to work with html using script though...